# Visitor-Pattern vs. open/closed principle: how to add new visitable object?

Tags: java, visitor-pattern, open-closed-principle

I'm studying the visitor pattern and I wonder how this pattern is related to the open/closed principle. I read on several websites that "*It is one way to follow the open/closed principle.*" (citated from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)).

On [another website](http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html) I learned that is follows the open/closed principle in such a way that it is easy to add new visitors to your program in order to "*extend existing funcionality without changing existing code*". That same website mentions that this visitor pattern has a major drawback: "*If a new visitable object is added to the framework structure all the implemented visitors need to be modified.*" A solution for this problem is provided by using Java's Reflection framework.

Now, isn't this solution a bit of a hack solution? I mean, I found this solution on some other blogs as well, but the code looks more like a workaround!

Is there another solution to this problem of adding new visitables to an existing implementation of the visitor pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Visitor* is one of the most boilerplate-ridden patterns of all and has the drawbacks regarding non-extensibility that you mention. It is itself a sloppy workaround to introduce double dispatch into a single-dispatch language. When you consider all its drawbacks, resorting to reflection is not such a terrible choice.

In fact, reflection is not a very bad choice in any case: consider how much today's code is written in dynamic languages, in other words using nothing *but* reflection, and the applications don't fall apart because of it.

Type safety has its merits, certainly, but when you find yourself hitting the wall of static typing and single dispatch, embrace reflection without remorse. Note also that, with proper caching of `Method` objects, reflective method invocation is almost as fast as static invocation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on precisely what job the Visitor is supposed to accomplish, but in most cases, this is what `interface`s are for. Consider a `SortedSet`; the implementation needs to be able to compare the different objects in the set to know their ordering, but it doesn't need to understand anything else about the objects. The solution (for sorting by natural order) is to use the `Comparable` interface.